# Pandas pivot and group by?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to load a .csv extract then do some transformations with the ultimate goal of exporting the data set back out to a .csv.  I have a dataframe that is structured similarly to:

```
col1    col2    col3        col4
name1   Yes     string1     val1
name2           string1     val1
name3           string1     val1
name2   Yes     string2     val2
name3           string2     val2
name4           string2     val2
name3   Yes     string3     val3
name4           string3     val3
name5           string3     val3
```

and would like the output to appear like:

```
name1   name2   name3   name4   name5   col3        col4
Yes                                     string1     val1
        Yes                             string2     val2
                Yes                     string3     val3
```

I was able to use `.pivot()` to get the data in col1 and col2 from the original dataframe to appear as desired, but as far as I understand it, there's no way to include other columns with grouped values (col3 and col4 in this example) using `.pivot()`, and it appears as though `.pivot_table()` won't work for my purposes.  The remaining problem I have using `.pivot()` is that when the new index is formed, I lose the ability to join back to those other grouped columns (again, col3 and col4 here).

Am I heading down the right path?  Or is there a better way of approaching what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the missing values actual empty strings or `NaN`?

Comment: Originally, it's a .csv, but when it's loaded into a dataframe, they become NaN, and after pivoting, if there was no value in col2, those would be NaN as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use argument `dropna=False` to keep the groups which only have missing values:

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index='col3', 
                     columns='col1', 
                     values='col2', 
                     aggfunc=lambda x: x, 
                     dropna=False)


col1    name1 name2 name3 name4 name5
col3                                 
string1   Yes   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
string2   NaN   Yes   NaN   NaN   NaN
string3   NaN   NaN   Yes   NaN   NaN
```

To convert `NaN` to empty strings, use argument `fill_value`:

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index='col3', 
                     columns='col1', 
                     values='col2', 
                     aggfunc=lambda x: x, 
                     dropna=False,
                     fill_value='')

col1    name1 name2 name3 name4 name5
col3                                 
string1   Yes                        
string2         Yes                  
string3               Yes
```

To remove the index and column attribute name, use `rename_axis`:

```
piv = (df.pivot_table(index='col3', 
                     columns='col1', 
                     values='col2', 
                     aggfunc=lambda x: x, 
                     dropna=False,
                     fill_value='')
       .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
      )

        name1 name2 name3 name4 name5
string1   Yes                        
string2         Yes                  
string3               Yes
```

Comment: I believe I'm following what you've done here, but I'm regretting not being clearer about the fact that I can't use col3 as an index, because I essentially have 50 fact columns just like col3 that will all be grouped together following the pivot of col1 and col2.  Hopefully I'm making sense?

Comment: No, can you adjust your input data to make it clear?

Comment: I added col4 that illustrates the extrapolation I'm referring to.  I have many more columns that would be tacked onto the data set in the same way.

Comment: hmm you just have to add those to the index as well, so `index=['col3', 'col4']` then add `reset_index()` after `rename_axis`. That should work

Comment: Ahh, interesting.  I didn't realize you could have multiple columns in the index.  I'll give it a try when I have a chance and will report back.  Thanks for your input here!

Comment: I started playing with the list of columns passed to the index parameter of `pivot_table()` and I believe there are just too many columns.  Eventually I got to the point where it would run without running out of memory (or returning an empty dataframe as it did originally upon passing in all columns in a list), but the data in the dataframe returned wasn't formatted correctly (in addition to not having all the necessary columns).  I'm thinking that perhaps `pivot_table()` is unable to accommodate the amount of data I'm trying to pivot. Is there another approach I can employ?

Comment: You have to ask your question in a way that I can see the problem. Right now my code produces the output as expected from your question. It's hard to help you if I can't see the problem.

Comment: I've run into other issues with the data apart from this one and so will have to start at square one again.  But, as you were able to help me with this issue, I'll mark it as accepted.  Thank you for your time and assistance, Erfan.